# SQL Query need to add the "QuantityAvailable" for 2 rows together that have the same BranchCode and Partnumber

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the Data below. I want to keep the QuantityAvailable for the other columns but add/sum the data that matches the 0900-HSI and 0100-BLA. There is a long list of Part numbers (1000's) in the table that you dont see here. All you see is 1 Part number below to show the code.

This is the table data

| BranchID | BranchCode | PartNumber | SupplierCode | QuantityAvailable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0900-HSI | GP6504-12-12 | 19015 | 5 |
| 2 | 0100-BLA | GP6504-12-12 | 19015 | 1 |
| 3 | 0300-IGH | GP6504-12-12 | 19015 | 2 |
| 4 | 0200-SCA | GP6504-12-12 | 19015 | 0 |
| 5 | 0700-CLR | GP6504-12-12 | 19015 | 0 |

I want the output to be like this or

| BranchID | BranchCode | PartNumber | SupplierCode | QuantityAvailable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0900-HSI | GP6504-12-12 | 19015 | 6 |
| 2 | 0100-BLA | GP6504-12-12 | 19015 | 6 |
| 3 | 0300-IGH | GP6504-12-12 | 19015 | 2 |
| 4 | 0200-SCA | GP6504-12-12 | 19015 | 0 |
| 5 | 0700-CLR | GP6504-12-12 | 19015 | 0 |

Or like this, This is what i prefer.

| BranchID | BranchCode | PartNumber | SupplierCode | QuantityAvailable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0100-BLA | GP6504-12-12 | 19015 | 6 |
| 3 | 0300-IGH | GP6504-12-12 | 19015 | 2 |
| 4 | 0200-SCA | GP6504-12-12 | 19015 | 0 |
| 5 | 0700-CLR | GP6504-12-12 | 19015 | 0 |

Here is my query that i have tried but it doesnt SUM, it just put a "1" in the "QuantityAvailable" column, see below after my query

```
SELECT
[BranchID],
[BranchCode],
[PartNumber],
[SupplierCode],
sum(Case
When BranchCode = '0100-BLA' or BranchCode = '0900-HSI'
then 1
else QuantityAvailable
End) as QuantityAvailable
  
FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[mytable]
  
Where
PartType IN ('Part', 'Exchange')
AND
Inactive = 0
and
partnumber='GP6504-12-12'

Group by Branchid, BranchCode, PartNumber, SupplierCode
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to group BranchCode `0900-HSI` and `0100-BLA` as one.

You can use case expression to treat both of the BranchCode as one and then `SUM()` it with a window function

```
SELECT [BranchID],
       [BranchCode],
       [PartNumber],
       [SupplierCode],
       SUM(SUM(QuantityAvailable)) 
         over (partition by
                case when [BranchCode] in ('0900-HSI', '0100-BLA')
                     then '0900-HSI+0100-BLA' else [BranchCode] 
                     end)  as QuantityAvailable
FROM  [mydatabase].[dbo].[mytable]
Group by Branchid, BranchCode, PartNumber, SupplierCode
order by Branchid
```

The second format that you preferred is actually much simpler. Use a case expression to translate one BranchCode to the other and then perform the group by with sum on the outer query

```
SELECT BranchID = MAX(BranchID),
       BranchCode,
       PartNumber,
       SupplierCode,
       QuantityAvailable = SUM(QuantityAvailable)
FROM
(
    SELECT [BranchID],
           [BranchCode] = CASE WHEN BranchCode = '0900-HSI' 
                               THEN '0100-BLA' 
                               ELSE BranchCode END,
           [PartNumber],
           [SupplierCode],
           [QuantityAvailable]
    FROM   [mydatabase].[dbo].[mytable]
) AS T
Group by BranchCode, PartNumber, SupplierCode
Order by Branchid
```

Comment: We are close, but this query sums up all the quantities for the BranchCode for all parts, not just the partnumber that it matches.

Comment: Just add the necessary filtering required at the `WHERE` clause

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the filtering at the where clause. I still need all the other BranchCode and Partnumbers. I was thinking that maybe we could concat the BranchCode and Partnumber to make that a unique value and somehow change all the 0900-HSI to 0100-BLA to sum the quantities? I just dont know. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last 2 comments. Which part of the query that does not meet your requirement ? Please edit your question and include the additional sample data and the corresponding expected result. As far as this question, the query does provides the required results as stated in the question

Answer (score -1):

You miss something in CASE statement. Try this -

```
    SELECT
    [BranchID],
    [BranchCode],
    [PartNumber],
    [SupplierCode],
    sum(Case BranchCode
    WHEN '0100-BLA' THEN 1
    WHEN '0900-HSI' THEN 1
    ELSE QuantityAvailable
    End) as QuantityAvailable
      
    FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[mytable]
      
    Where
    PartType IN ('Part', 'Exchange')
    AND
    Inactive = 0
    and
    partnumber='GP6504-12-12'
    
    Group by Branchid, BranchCode, PartNumber, SupplierCode
```

Comment: I tried that query and came up with the same thing. The QuantityAvailable for the BranchCode 0100-BLA and the 0900-HSI are just coming up as 1

Comment: For the record, there is nothing wrong with the `case` expression that OP uses. It is just different syntax. You may refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)